# Is there a simple way to map nested data with Lodash?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash, pure-function

For my current project, I'm working with an API that returns data formatted like this:

```
{
  groups: [
    {
      items: [
        {
          points: [
            { name: "name1", ... },
            { name: "name2", ... },
            { name: "name3", ... },
            ...
          ],
          ...
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
    ...
  ],
  ...
};
```

I'd like to create a *pure function*, `mapValues`, that takes in an object in the above format, as well as an object mapping each `name` to a `value`, and returns the same structure, but with each `point` containing the `value` that corresponds to its `name`.

For example, calling `mapValues(data, { name1: "value1", name2: "value2", name3: "value3" })` should return this:

```
{
  groups: [
    {
      items: [
        {
          points: [
            { name: "name1", value: "value1", ... },
            { name: "name2", value: "value2", ... },
            { name: "name3", value: "value3", ... },
            ...
          ],
          ...
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
    ...
  ],
  ...
};
```

Here's my first pass:

```
function mapValues(data, values) {
  return _.extend({}, data, {
    groups: _.map(ui.groups, (group) => {
      return _.extend({}, group, {
        items: _.map(group.items, (item) => {
          return _.extend({}, item, {
            points: _.map(item.points, (point) => {
              return _.extend({ value: values[point.name] }, point);
            })
          });
        })
      });
    })
  });
}
```

That works, but there's quite a bit of nesting a duplicate code. For my second attempt, I reached for recursion.

```
function mapValues(data, values) {
  return (function recursiveMap(object, attributes) {
    if (attributes.length === 0) { return _.extend({ value: values[object.name] }, object); }
    let key = attributes[0];
    return _.extend({}, object, {
      [key]: _.map(object[key], child => recursiveMap(child, attributes.slice(1)))
    });
  })(ui, ["groups", "items", "points"]);
}
```

That works too, but it's difficult to read and not very concise.

**Is there a cleaner way to recursively map an object using Lodash? Ideally, I'm looking for a functional approach.**

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way you can do it using `Object.assign` and no fancy functions

```
var data = <your data here>;
var values = <your mapped values>;

data.groups.items.points.map(p=>
  Object.assign(p, {value: values[p.name]})
);
```

This works because arrays and objects are [pass by reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference). So any modifications to the values will result in the original being changed.

If you don't want to mutate your original dataset, it requires you to use `{}` as the first argument (to assign to a new, empty object) and show clear read/write paths for each object.

```
var newData = Object.assign({}, data,
  {groups:
    {items:
      {points: data.groups.items.points.map(p=>
        Object.assign({}, p, {value: values[p.name]})
      )}
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse! I think the problem here is that `groups` and `items` are also arrays, and your solution is treating them as objects.

Answer (score 0):

I know you wanted Lodash, but I had same issue some time ago and I've came up with this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hzcsze48/3/) I am using great tool created by [nervgh](https://github.com/nervgh/recursive-iterator). It is very simple yet usefull. You can adjust this function to be pure using `Object.assign`, accept key parameter and tweak it however you want. You get the idea.

```
function mapValues(data, values) {
  var iterator = new RecursiveIterator(data);
  for(let {node} of iterator) {
    if(node.hasOwnProperty('name')) {
        node.value = values[node.name];
    }
  }
  return data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I like the concept of a recursive iterator, but this solution appears to modify the values in place, and I was hoping for a pure, functional solution. By pure, I mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function

Comment: You can always use `Object.assign` to avoid mutating data object, and create iterator of this "copied" object and then return it.